# Can anyone explain most popular RSA attacks like I'm 5?

Tags: rsa

Suppose I implement RSA myself in C and I use just the formulas from number theory. What attacks would my implementation be vulnerable to? Can anyone explain this to me like I'm 5?

Comment: RSA is a trapdoor permutation used in various protocols and cryptographic schemes. The attacks are on the protocol/scheme and the primitive together. What scheme are you implementing?

Comment: Shall we assume textbook RSA with no message padding / formatting?

Comment: Not my answer, but a quick search turned up http://members.tripod.com/irish_ronan/rsa/attacks.html which is about as simple an explanation as I've seen.

Comment: Additionally, there are sidechannel attacks. E.g. the decryption is done with square-and-multiply exponentiation, then the timing is a linear function of the Hamminh weight of the key (n times squaring and the Hamming weight in multiplications). If the 0s and 1s are almost uniform, this is not a problem, but otherwise you have a problem. If the attacker can even identify the order of multiplications and squaring (the operations take different amounts of time and cache access), he can just grab $d$ directly.

Comment: @rath Yes, textbook RSA with no message padding or formatting.

Comment: Textbook RSA is not probabilistic and it is malleable.

Comment: @ddddavidee What do you mean by malleable?

Comment: I mean that you can modify the ciphertext to get a modification (under you control) on the plaintext. I'll try to add a reference here when I get access to my computer. At the moment you could check this Wikipedia page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)

Comment: Dolev, Danny; Dwork, Cynthia; Naor, Moni (2000). "Nonmalleable Cryptography". SIAM Journal on Computing 30 (2): 391–437. doi:10.1137/S0097539795291562.